# Wordpress rewrite post gallery image url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

By default, I have an attachment page URL:

```
http://example.lt/photo/juokingi-pokalbiai-22-nuotraukos/attachment/221/
```

I want have:

```
http://example.lt/photo/juokingi-pokalbiai-22-nuotraukos/gallery/221/
```

or:

```
http://example.lt/photo/juokingi-pokalbiai-22-nuotraukos/221/
```

or:

```
http://example.lt/photo/juokingi-pokalbiai-22-nuotraukos/img_name
```

Is it possible to rewrite the attached images URL?

In permalinks settings, I cant set additional URL only for tags and category, how about attachments?

Comment: The last one's a bit problematic. How do you want `img_name` to translate to attachment id? Is the `juokingi...nuotraukos` part always static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# for /photo/juokingi-pokalbiai-22-nuotraukos/gallery/221/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/gallery/(\d+)/?$ $1/attachment/$2 [NC,L]

# if "photo/juokingi-pokalbiai-22-nuotraukos" path is static followed by id
RewriteRule ^(photo/juokingi-pokalbiai-22-nuotraukos)/(\d+)/?$ $1/attachment/$2 [NC,L]
```

Unless, the image name also contains the attachment id; handling a URL like `/photo/juokingi-pokalbiai-22-nuotraukos/img_name` would not be possible.